# Как декодировать base64/xor/base64

Tags: python-3.x, base64, xor

Есть такой вот шифрованный ник в программе обвернутый в base64 -> xor -> base64

`HywgFSkWASIEQRwFMyMbHw==`
Как правильно его расшифровать и по необходимости обратно зашифровать в python?
Метод шифрования и дешифрования base64 xor base64
Ключ от xor -> `Niffs`

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: base64 это просто способ записи байтиков. А как там зашифрованно вы нам не сказали.

Comment: Вообще то это логин создающийся в приложении в купленной мною программой и я хочу понять как дешифровать и зашифровать в python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, вы же указали последовательность "дешифровки". Осталось просто её записать на Питоне.

```
import base64

b64_str = "HywgFSkWASIEQRwFMyMbHw=="
xor_list = "Niffs".encode()

# туда
bytes_str = base64.b64decode(b64_str.encode('ascii'))
bytes_xor_str = bytes(bytes_str[i] ^ xor_list[i % len(xor_list)] for i in range(len(bytes_str)))
out = base64.b64decode(bytes_xor_str).decode('ascii')
print(out)
```

```php
@AlexCodePHP
```

Обратное преобразование ничуть не сложнее, т.к. отличается только заменой функции `b64decode` на `b64encode`.

```
# сюда
b64_out = base64.b64encode(out.encode('ascii'))
bytes_xor_out = bytes(b64_out[i] ^ xor_list[i % len(xor_list)] for i in range(len(b64_out)))
new_b64_str = base64.b64encode(bytes_xor_out).decode('ascii')
print(new_b64_str)

assert b64_str == new_b64_str
```

---

И вообще, оба преобразования можно оформить одной функцией.

```
import base64

def convert(inp_str, xor_str, func):
    b64 = func(inp_str.encode('ascii'))
    xor_list = xor_str.encode()
    l = len(xor_list)
    return func(bytes(b64[i] ^ xor_list[i % l] for i in range(len(b64)))).decode('ascii')

b64_str = "HywgFSkWASIEQRwFMyMbHw=="
xor_str = "Niffs"
decoded = convert(b64_str, xor_str, base64.b64decode)
print(decoded)
encoded = convert(decoded, xor_str, base64.b64encode)
print(encoded)
assert b64_str == encoded
```

```php
@AlexCodePHP
HywgFSkWASIEQRwFMyMbHw==
```